# The button for convert a reply to comment would have to exclude review comments

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderator-tools

I have a problem with the moderation button to convert a reply to comment, and is that when I put the following option:

> Migrate all comments also in this answer.

This includes also those that were generated since the **revision**, which seems to me incorrect. It would be good to always exclude the comments that were generated since the review.

Example:

[image: @Mariano low quality comment.]

That comment ends on the question, so you see this *"This does not provide an answer"*, and one thinks, clearly not, because it is a question.

But there is also another problem ... A **@UserName** should be added at the beginning of each comment in the response, the username being the owner of the response. In this way, when the response becomes a comment, it is clear that it responds to the response turned into comment and not to the question.

Comment: AFAIK- review comments are in no way special. I typically just nuke any comment I don't want converted then convert